# pass EJS variable to be used in client side <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I have a EJS variable i use to render a list of products in my template; `prodArray`. EJS lists these in `<div>`'s and each has three buttons. These buttons are controlled by jQuery scripts and I would like jQuery to have access to the `prodArray` array. I would like a way to pass the EJS local variable to a client side script like so.

```
<script>
  var prodArray = <%= prodArray %> 
</script>
```

It's not this simple for me unfortunately. The script gives an error.
If i try to call `prodArray` in my client side javascript it gives the error that it is undefined.

`prodArray` contains date objects and id objects that need to passed along without turning to `undefined`. Maybe I'm missing something really simple as can't find anyone else with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code as requested: (I'm currently working on it. It's a mess. current work around to my problem is to save the objectId of each product as a string in a hidden `p` tag. But this is not what I want... I would much be able to pass the array on to my script as a whole.)

EJS:

```
<h2>Producnts</h2>
<p>You currently have <%= prodArray.length %> active products. </p>
<a href="/camphome/products/new" class="btn btn-info">Add New Product</a>

<% prodArray.forEach(function (product,idx) { %>
<% var editlink = "/camphome/products/edit/" + product._id %>
<% var removelink = "/camphome/products/remove/" + product._id %>
  <div class="prod">

    <!--<div class="prodImage"></div>-->
    <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
    <p>Starting: <span class="moment"><%= moment(product.startDate).format('MMM Do YYYY hh:mm') %></span><br/>
    Other Starting: 
    Places: <%= product.places.max %><br/>
    Number Booked: <%= product.places.booked %><br/>
    Price: €<%= product.cost %> 
    </p>
    <p hidden class="prodIdx"><%= idx %></p>
    <p hidden class="prodId"><%= product._id %></p>
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button" href="<%= editlink %>">Edit Product</a>
    <% if (product.places.booked > 1 || 1===1) { %>
      <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button" href="<%= removelink %>">Remove Product</a>
    <% } %>
    <!--<span hidden class="prodId" value="<%= product._id %>"></span>-->
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm reserveButton" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#selfReserve">Reserve Place(s)</a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="selfReserve" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Reserve places on your own product.</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="selfReserveForm" action="" method="post">
              <input class="form-control" name="selProd" id="selProd" type="hidden"></input>
              <input class="form-control" name="action" id="action" type="hidden" value="reserve"></input>
              <p>How many Places?</p>
              <label for="reserveNum"></label>
              <input class="form-control" style="width:30%" id="reserveNum" name="reserveNum" type="number" min='1' max="<%= product.places.max - product.places.booked %>" id="selfReservePlaces"></input>
              <br/>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Modal-->
  </div>
<% }) %>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var prodArray = <%= prodArray %>; //THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE!!.
// DIRTY WORK AROUND BELOW!!
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.reserveButton').click(function () {
      //var prodIdx = $(this).siblings('.prodIdx').text();
      //console.log(prodIdx);
      var ID = $(this).siblings('.prodId').text();
      $('#selProd').val(ID)
    })
});
</script>
```

INDEX.js

```
router.get('/products', function (req,res, next) {
  var Product = mongoose.model('products');
  Product.find({campID:req.user.data._id})
  .sort({startDate:1})
  .exec( function (error, results){
    res.render('camphome',{
      title: 'Products',
      middle: 'products',
      classname: 'products',
      prodArray: results,
      moment: moment,
      socialIcons: socialIcons,
      user: req.user,
      userdata: req.user.data,
      isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: How is the generated HTML when you load the page in your browser ?

Comment: Works fine, renders as I want it. It's only that I don't know how to pass the variable to my jQuery scripts.

Comment: Can you give us the code when it is generated ? We need it to seed where is the problem.

Comment: What is the result of : 
`<script>
  var prodArray = <%= prodArray %> 
</script>`
When it is generated

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`

Comment: Right-click -> view source, in your browser, thx

Comment: If I request the code result, it's because I want to see, what the `<%= prodArray %>` code generate to give you the best answer.